# Since the rename, posts from the feeds user don't have the same styling or all the elements

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, meta

Adding on the previous bug reports, the Feeds user that posts recent Meta topics to The Town Hall, don't have the same styling or all the elements of previous posts.

Example of how it looks now:

[image: Current Onebox]

Example of how it used to look:

[image: Previous Onebox]

Things that appear to be changed now:

- Current Score
- Avatar of user posting the question
- Icon of the site (on the right)
- More white space surrounding the question

---

Other (seemingly) related issues:

- [Meta posts don't onebox](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/223/78)
- [Meta posts don't load from mobile apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244616/186281)
- [Community Building doesn't exist in Data Explorer](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/78)

Answer (score 6):

This will be fixed as of build 2782 (it affects Computer Graphics Meta too).